# Is it reckless to use an Android app to login to a server with SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, android

There is a very similar question [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117700/is-it-safe-to-use-an-android-server-monitoring-app-to-login-to-a-server-with-ss).

Recently I came across an Android app that facilitates SSH and requires no permissions. Specifically, "Telnet / SSH Simple Client" by Advanced Planning Corp..

Does the fact that it does not require permissions make it a secure choice? Or is it still overly risky? Are there any "best practices" that a novice should be aware of?

Are there any consensus choice open-source offerings?

Comment: The gap between "secure" and "overly risky" is huge. Best practice: Give your keys and/or passwords only to devices and software you trust.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser Well, perhaps my phrase choice of "best practices" was ill-advised, as best practice is not always practical. To remote login using SSH seems to implies the use of at least some hardware or software that is not definitely secure. My main question is if using an SSH app is a huge no-no or not. Can you weigh in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A SSH or telnet client does not need specific permissions. It only needs to open a socket to a remote server, i.e. similar to a web browser, mail client etc. And network access is not considered a special permission any longer.

This means the use of permissions does not say anything about the security in this case: one could write a SSH client which is secure and does not need special permissions the same as one would be able to write a client which is insecure even though special permissions are required. In fact I would be more suspicious if the client would need special permissions like reading the contacts or location, because none of these is needed inside a SSH client.

Comment: I agree; I viewed the fact that the app didn't require special permissions as favorable. And good point on network access no longer being considered a special permission. Do you know of any consensus apps for this purpose, or any open source options?

Comment: @d0rmLife: I cannot recommend any specific apps.